# Specified Trace Colors not looping through entire Dash chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have a dataframe that looks like this where I am plotting voter registration for political parties across the 27 districts of New York between the years 2014-2018:

[image]

Using Dash, I wanted to specify the colors for my individual traces using the following code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

# Read in the data 

districts = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/thedatasleuth/New-York-Congressional-Districts/blob/master/districts.csv?raw=True")

df = districts

# Get a list of all the years
years = districts['Year'].unique()

# Create the app
app = dash.Dash()

# Populate the layout with HTML and graph components
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H2("New York Congressional Districts"),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id="Year",
                options=[{
                    'label': i,
                    'value': i
                } for i in years],
                value='All Years'),
        ],
        style={'width': '25%',
               'display': 'inline-block'}),
    dcc.Graph(id='funnel-graph'),
])


# Add the callbacks to support the interactive componets
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('funnel-graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('Year', 'value')])
def update_graph(Year):
    if Year == "All Years":
        df_plot = df.copy()
    else:
        df_plot = df[df['Year'] == Year]

    trace1 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('DEM')], name='DEM', 
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(3,67,223)']))
    trace2 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('REP')], name='REP',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(229,0,0)']))
    trace3 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('CON')], name='CON',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(132,0,0)']))
    trace4 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('WOR')], name='WOR',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(149,208,252)']))
    trace5 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('IND')], name='IND',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(126,30,156)']))
    trace6 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('GRE')], name='GRE',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(21,176,26)']))
    trace7 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('WEP')], name='WEP',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(255,129,192)']))
    trace8 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('REF')], name='REF',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(206,162,253)']))
    trace9 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('OTH')], name='OTH',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(249,115,6)']))
    trace10 = go.Bar(x=df_plot ['DISTRICT'], y=df_plot [('BLANK')], name='BLANK',
                    marker=dict(color=['rgb(101,55,0)']))


    return {
        'data': [trace1, trace2, trace3, trace4, trace5, 
                     trace6, trace7, trace8, trace9, trace10],
        'layout':
        go.Layout(
            title='{}'.format(Year),
            barmode='group')
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.server.run(port=8000, host='127.0.0.1')
```

However, the colors I want are only showing up in the first district as opposed to all 27 districts as seen [here](https://ny-districts-by-year.herokuapp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the colors out of the list like this:

`marker=dict(color='rgb(3,67,223)'))`